# How to Send Data to SAP From ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, netweaver

Please, Guide for - "**How to send data to SAP From Asp.Net application ?**"

Till, Now I know this much.

1. SAP people give us WSDL file (Definition of Web Service)...

Guide me with step by step implementation. . .

Thank You.

Manoj Kalla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is **very** broad. I'll just give a quick outline of the steps you need to take to send data to SAP using the `wsdl` you have received.

1. Create a proxy class based on the `wsdl` file.

   First you need to create a `C#` or `VB.Net` class from the `wsdl` file. You can do
   this either directly in `Visual Studio` by adding a web or a service reference. Exactly how
   this is done depends on the Visual Studio version.

   You can also generate the proxy class using either `wsdl.exe` or `svcutil.exe`. Google these
   terms and you should find many tutorials and samples, no doubt many here on Stack Overflow.
2. After the proxy class is created and made available in you project, you create an instance of the class. Then you create an instance of that class the represent the data to be sent to SAP. This class would have been created for you based on the `wsdl`.
3. Use the proxy class to call the method for sending the data-representation class to the service exposed by SAP.
4. Process the response from the SAP service. This steps depends on what the service sends back.

Comment: Dear sir,  I had added reference to visual studio and its created a Class File, also by WSDL.EXE. Step 3 and 4 can you explain in detail . .  Many thanks to you. . .